# Is the sum of first $n$ factorials a square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the values of $n\geq 1$ for which $1!+2!+\cdots+n!$ is a square.

I wanted to go through some small $n$..

$1!=1$

$1!+2!=3$ not a square

$1!+2!+3!=9$ a square

$1!+2!+3!+4!=33$ not a square

$1!+2!+3!+4!+5!=153$ not a square

$1!+2!+3!+4!+5!+6!=873$ not a square

Here comes a pattern... All $n!$ for $n\geq 5$ ends with $0$ because   $5\cdot 2$ is factor of  $5!$.

So, $1!+2!+\cdots+n!$ for $n\geq 5$ ends with $3$ so can not be a square..

See that unit digit of a square can only be one of $0,1,4,5,6,9$..

So, only possible $n$ are $1,3$

I just want to know if there are any gaps.

Comment: Sounds about right.

Comment: Your argument is totaly valid: good job.

Comment: The body of the question and the title doesn't match.

Comment: You suggest some thing that would match @user170039

Comment: "Is sum of the $n$ factorials not a square?", maybe?